# Blitz procedure failing

Tags: sql-server, configuration, sp-blitz

When I run the latest version of sp_blitz I get the following:
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

> Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_Blitz, Line 3467
>
> `INSERT` failed because the following `SET` options have incorrect settings: '`QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`'. Verify that `SET` options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

It seems no one else is having this problem except me. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In SSMS settings, make sure the SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER box is checked. That should fix it.

[image]